# Why does Joe Haldeman reference education in mathematics in lots of his stories?

Tags: joe-haldeman

In numerous stories by Joe Haldeman, the protagonist's education in mathematics is mentioned even if it's quite irrelevant to the plot.

Has he said why that is?  Did he study mathematics himself, or regret that he didn't?

Comment: His bio states that he has a B.S. in Astronomy and a year of postgrad work in math/CS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In "An Autobiographical Ramble by Joe Haldeman", [Autobiographical Ramble](http://www.joehaldeman.com/biography/autobiographical-ramble), he says:

> ...When September came around, I signed up as a part-time graduate student, so I'd have more time to write. On the first day of classes, I found out that the professor who was teaching the one I really needed -- Simulation of Physical Systems -- had run off to another university, leaving his notes with a graduate student who promised he'd try to stay one week ahead of us. I quit. I sat down and wrote the two chapters and outline for War Year and sent them to Bova. Two weeks later, I had a contract from Holt, Rinehart and Winston. **I dropped out of mathematics and never looked back**.